# LinkSys router suddenly cannot get an IP address

Tags: router, dhcp, ip-address

I have a linksys router WRT54G2 connected to a cable broadband. Just last week, everything was working perfectly - I would be able to connect my laptop to the internet using WiFi.

However, starting last week, I suddenly lost my internet connection. At first I thought something was wrong with my ISP. However, when I tried connecting the cable directly to my laptop, I found out that there was no problem with the internet connection after all.

It appears that it is only my router that cannot get IP address. I have already tried cloning my MAC address and reconfiguring my router using the setup CD, but nothing worked.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: What's the model of Cable Modem? If it's a DOCSIS 1.1 modem it might have been phased out; I've seen this a lot lately.

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure what to call this cable, but this one was supplied to me by my ISP. The cable is connected to a canopy on my roof. The model is PSA15R-295 (Motorola). Was this info helpful?

Comment: @Chris Since OP can get an IP address on the laptop, we know it's not an issue with the modem.

Answer (score 1):

Update the firmware. LinkSys firmware is made from pixie dust. Tinkerbell might have escaped so you need a fresh sprite to take her place.

Seriously, any firmware that starts with L and ends with inkSys should not be trusted. Update the firmware to the latest version. Consider switching to DD-WRT. I've had spontaneous failures like this with the LinkSys devices I've had the displeasure of managing and often a reboot or firmware upgrade "fixed" it.

It's the closest thing to voodoo I've ever encountered in this profession.

**EDIT**: Sounds stupid, but have you rebooted the thing via a power cycle?

Comment: i've also seen both Linksys and Netgear routers simply die for no apparent reason, even with 3rd-party firmware.  maybe power spikes fried them, i don't know.  but yeah, if you can still flash firmware onto the device, reflashing with DD-WRT or OpenWRT or Tomato is a good thing to try.

Comment: +1 "LinkSys firmware is made from pixie dust. Tinkerbell might have escaped so you need a fresh sprite to take her place" for AWESOME.

Comment: In addition to powercycling the router and ensuring it's configured properly to get a DHCP ID from the modem, you might need to powercycle the modem after the router is connected. In the past, I've seen situations where the modem/gateway will only distribute IPs to the MAC addresses that were plugged into it when it booted.

Answer (score 0):

After trying the latest firmware, you may need to consider that your router has passed on to the big bit bucket in the heavens.

Answer (score 0):

Some ISP modems have a built in DHCP server (i.e. it gives IP's). Therefore your Linksys router should become a switch. Try disabling DHCP on your Linksys. If you can't get to it, hard-reset it and hook it up directly to a computer.